# Splitting variables after importing from SPSS

Tags: r, import, split

I will be frank and say that I'm pretty new to statistical programming with R. I'm excited to stuck in, but need some help getting my environment set up.

I imported my data from SPSS (which I was using previously) and am now trying to separate out my variables so that I can start running my models.

However, I don't seem to be able to pin down a function for splitting out the variables automatically.

I'm almost sure that what I'm looking for is the split() function (no surprises there), but I don't know how to tell R that I want to split according to the heading of the variable (e.g. gender, ethnicity etc.)

This is what my import looks like:

[the three variables I want to split - gender, ethnicity and BMI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XMIb.png)

Thanks!

Comment: I assume you want to model the variable _bmi_. If so, your data is already formatted into variables: gender and ethnicity. R can model those as factors if that's what you want. No need to "split" your variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Partition Node to do that but if you want to split the analysis using gender, for example, you can also use the select node and split in as many categories you want to.

**Example:**
In the first select node -> include:  *gender matches '*Female*'*

In the second select node -> include:  *gender matches '*Male*'*

Later, you can copy and paste the analysis made in other categories and build a model or indicator splitted by the categories chosen.

PS: Inside the Models Nodes you can also choose a variable to be used as partition. You just have to put a Type node with the variable's roles and then connect to the model using the option pre-defined roles inside the model node.